# Search and extract XML nodes by an attribute

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I have some difficulties at extracting a specific XML node. Here is an example:

```
<group name="syslog,">
  <rule id="01" level="0" noalert="1">
    <category>syslog</category>
    <description>Generic template for all syslog rules.</description>
  </rule>
</group>

<group name="firewall,">
  <rule id="02" level="0" noalert="1">
    <category>firewall</category>
    <description>Generic template for all firewall rules.</description>
  </rule>
</group>
```

Let's suppose an user will input the value "02" for id. I want to extract the whole rule node with the id attribute = 02, the following result will be:

```
<rule id="02" level="0" noalert="1">
    <category>firewall</category>
    <description>Generic template for all firewall rules.</description>
</rule>
```

I want this node to append on another xml file, or just write it on a QPlainTextEdit. How can I do this using Qt XML classes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go simple, console application to do this:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QXmlStreamReader>
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    const QString xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
                      "<document>\n"
                      "    <group name=\"syslog,\">\n"
                      "        <rule id=\"01\" level=\"0\" noalert=\"1\">\n"
                      "            <category>syslog</category>\n"
                      "            <description>Generic template for all syslog rules.</description>\n"
                      "        </rule>\n"
                      "    </group>\n"
                      "    <group name=\"firewall,\">\n"
                      "        <rule id=\"02\" level=\"0\" noalert=\"1\">\n"
                      "            <category>firewall</category>\n"
                      "            <description>Generic template for all firewall rules.</description>\n"
                      "        </rule>\n"
                      "    </group>\n"
                      "</document>\n";
    QXmlStreamReader xmlReader(xml);
    std::string id;

    std::cout << "Enter ID: ";
    std::cin >> id;

    qint64 start = 0, stop = 0;

    while(!xmlReader.atEnd() && !xmlReader.hasError()) {
        qint64 offset = xmlReader.characterOffset();
        QXmlStreamReader::TokenType token = xmlReader.readNext();

        if(token == QXmlStreamReader::StartDocument) {
            continue;
        }

        if(token == QXmlStreamReader::EndDocument) {
            break;
        }

        if(token == QXmlStreamReader::StartElement) {
            if (xmlReader.name() == "rule") {
                QXmlStreamAttributes attrs = xmlReader.attributes();
                if (attrs.count() > 0) {
                    if (attrs.at(0).name() == "id" && attrs.at(0).value().toString() == QString::fromStdString(id)) {
                        start = offset-1;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(start > 0 && token == QXmlStreamReader::EndElement) {
            if (xmlReader.name() == "rule") {
                stop = xmlReader.characterOffset();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (xmlReader.hasError()) {
        qDebug() << "ERROR:" << xmlReader.errorString();
    } else if (start > 0 && stop > 0) {
        qDebug() << start << "/" << stop << "\n";
        QStringRef subString(&xml, static_cast<int>(start), static_cast<int>(stop-start));
        qDebug() << subString;
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

The example treats ID as text, so input from keyboard should contain leading zeroes ("01" or "02").

There is nothing special in this code, except that we need to "catch" characterOffset of previous tag during looking for opening rule tag. That's because offset is pointing at the end of currently readed tag. So we read offest at the beginning of each iteration of while loop, and then we jump to next element.
When we have opening and closing positions of rule tags, it's easy to get to  part of source xml which we are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for help buddy, I understood the code and adapted to my application and it's working! Cheers!